# Getting images from Instagram, always null

Tags: php, image, instagram

I develop a small script on localhost (WAMP server, CURL enabled) to retrieve images from Instagram. Based on this script: [see tutorial](http://www.blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-instagram-api-fancybox-simplified) I have also set up the variables on Instagram. I'm not sure what is wrong more specifically or how to solve it (probably with authentication).

- USER ID
- CLIENT ID
- CLIENT SECRET
- WEBSITE URL
- REDIRECT URI

This is my user
http://instagram.com/krondorl

```
function fetchData($url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $result;
}

$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/280766222/media/recent/?access_token=df04c6989eaf4490bdac1f82554182bb");
$result = json_decode($result);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: surely that last bit should be in a for loop? otherwise you'd only get one image. are you sure the access token is right?

Comment: I get a `OAuthAccessTokenException` exception stating that the `access_token` is invalid. The code is working if I replace the url with one from my own app with a valid access_token. In other words, there's nothing wrong with the above code, it's your url that's invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below which works for me. Make sure your URL is correct.

```
$json_url  ='https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/280766222/media/recent/?access_token=df04c6989eaf4490bdac1f82554182bb';

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') 
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$results =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string

$json_decoded = json_decode($results);
```

By the way I check your URL which happens to be incorrect and give me the below error.

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","code":400,"error_message":"The \"access_token\" provided is invalid."}}
```

Before you trying the code, try the URL on the browser and see whether the URL is correct.

Comment: Thanks.

To be honest I don't even know how to register the token. I have made that weeks ago but not sure how to repeat. Another thing is working on localhost. Does that work with Instagram tokens?

Where to ask this process? On serverfault?

Comment: read the Instagram API. You have to create a token to access their stuff.

Comment: Your URL should look somewhat like this var https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/parkslope/media/recent?count=4&access_token=10239.2fa8a45.08f28ab239bf42a29a70321b2bad4ef0

Comment: Do you know about using localhost as callback?